# storing database connection in application

Tags: asp-classic, database-connection, ado

I am thinking of storing database connection in application to increse performance.

I have a website with min. 10.000 realtime visitors.
the daily pageviews is more than 1.5 million.

i create database connection with ado on the page top

and kill it on the page bottom.

if i store this connection in application and call it when i need, is this will be smart?

if application didn't create or application pool is cleaned, i will create application for databse connection
if application has the databasea connection i will skip this step.

please give me advice

Answer (score 1):

A lot of folks store their connection string in an Application variable.  It can be defined in the global.asa file.

Others like to put all their information into an include file and approach reusability that way.

I've never seen speed / performance comparison stats for the two.

For additional thoughts just google your question.  it has been discussed many times.

Answer (score 0):

> Putting a recordset or application into application or session scope
>   leads to:
>
> - serialization of requests
> - thread-affinity of request
> - wasted memory in the case of session variables
> - a bottle-neck in the case of application variables

More information:

http://learnasp.com/freebook/asp/nodbsession.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My CPU was at least %90.

I tried storing database connection and connection object in global.asa

Here is the result;

The site is same, number of real time visitors is same.
Now, my CPU is at most %5.

So this is perfect result.